# Oracle INSTR find exact match

Tags: oracle

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
v_version_string := '2016.0.1|2016.0.2|2016.1|2016.0.4';
v_version := '2016';

BEGIN
IF (INSTR(v_version_string, v_version) > 0) THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Found');
  ELSE 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Not found');
END IF;
END;
```

The above returns "Found", which is correct.  However, I want to do an **exact** match.  If v_version is 2016, I want it to return "Not found" in the v_version_string delimited by |.  Is there an easier/quicker way to do this without splitting the v_version_string by | in to an array and looping through the array? If v_version is 2016.0.1, then it should say "Found", which it will in the above script.  However, it should say "Not found" for 2016.  RegEx?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it a regex? Try: `(2016.0.1|2016.0.2|2016.1|2016.0.4)$`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an alternative to a regular expression, you could add delimiters to the start and end of the list string (so it becomes `'|2016.0.1|2016.0.2|2016.1|2016.0.4|'`), and to the search string (so it becomes `'|2016|'`). Then plain `instr` will only match the whole search string:

```
IF (INSTR('|'||v_version_string||'|', '|'||v_version||'|') > 0) THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Found');
  ELSE 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Not found');
END IF;
```

If the `v_version_string` and/or `v_version` values can sometimes have leading and trailing delimiters, you can strip them (if they are there) before re-adding them:

```
IF (INSTR('|'|| TRIM('|' from v_version_string) ||'|',
     '|'|| TRIM('|' from v_version) ||'|') > 0) THEN
```

That would find a match with `v_version` set to `'2016.0.1'` or `'|2016.0.1|'`, etc.

---

If you do want to use a regular expression you can look for delimiters (or start/end) around your search value:

```
IF (REGEXP_INSTR(v_version_string, '(^|\|)'||v_version||'(\||$)') > 0) THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Found');
  ELSE 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Not found');
END IF;
```

And you can trim the `v_version` if necessary; you don't need to trim the `v_version_string`. But I think that's slightly less intuitive, as well as potentially less efficient for a lot of data.

Comment: Thanks!  However, it does not work for this scenario when v_version = |2016.0.1|:

    `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
    declare
    v_version_string VARCHAR  (100) := '|2016.0.1|2016.0.2|2016.1|2016.0.4|';
    v_version VARCHAR(50) := '|2016.0.1|';
    begin
      IF (INSTR('|'||v_version_string||'|', '|'||v_version||'|') > 0) THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Found');
      ELSE 
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Not found');
      END IF;
end;`

Comment: You mean if the string and search value are already delimited? If that's the case you don't need to modify them, your original plain `instr` would work. Can you have both?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear earlier.  I want to run the script with different values.  For example: v_version can be 2016 or it can be 2016.0.1 or it can be 2016.0.2.  In my example: when I run with 2016, it should not find it.  When I run with 2016.0.1, it should say found it.

Comment: But can it also be `|2016.0.1|'? And can v_version_string also have leading and trailing delimiters?

Comment: Got it.  So I am declaring as below and it works (I do not put leading and trailing delimiter for the string to be found - search string, but only in the string that is to be searched - list string):

`SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
declare
v_version_string VARCHAR(100) := '|2016.0.1|2016.0.2|2016.1|2016.0.4|';
v_version VARCHAR(50) := '2016';
begin
  IF (INSTR('|'||v_version_string||'|', '|'||v_version||'|') > 0) THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Found');
  ELSE 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Not found');
END IF;
end;`

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Code in comments doesn't really work... I updated the answer to add a trim. If your `v_version_string` *always* has leading and trailing delimiters then you don't need to trim *or* concatenate that though, based on your last comment.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help Alex.  :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to used REGEXP_INSTR  function .